# Java - Importar Excel com combo e checkbox

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, checkbox, apache-poi

Preciso realizar uma importação de planilha excel, utilizando o java. Só que a planilha possui valores de seleção como listas checkbox e combos. Como no exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem um exemplo de código java que consiga recuperar esses valores, com Apache poi, JExcel ou qualquer outro em Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resolução com o Apache POI.

A leitura do combobox será feita do mesmo modo de uma célula normal. O único detalhe está na leitura do checkbox. Esse campo é um booleano, ao configurá-lo você irá indicar qual a célula irá receber o true/false. Você deverá pegar o valor que deseja dessa célula. No meu caso, eu configurei o checkbox da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso significa que independente de onde o checkbox esteja, ao marcá-lo ou desmarcá-lo, o valor do checkbox(true/falso) será armazenado na célula C7.

Excel exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo de código:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try (
            InputStream inputStream = ReadExcelControls.class.getResourceAsStream("readControls.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        ) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("teste");
            Cell nomeComum = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1);
            Cell classificacaoEspecie = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(1);
            Cell envenenamento = sheet.getRow(6).getCell(2);

            //Campo normal
            System.out.println("Nome Comum: " + nomeComum.getStringCellValue());
            //Combobox
            System.out.println("Classificação Espécie: " + classificacaoEspecie.getStringCellValue());
            //Checkbox
            System.out.println("Evenenamento: " + envenenamento.getBooleanCellValue());
        }
    }
```